# slow left join using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Here is the SQL query in question:

```
select *  from company1 
left join company2 on company2.model 
    LIKE CONCAT(company1.model,'%') 
    where company1.manufacturer = company2.manufacturer
```

company1 contains 2000 rows while company2 contains 9000 rows.

The query takes around 25 seconds to complete.

I have company1.model and company2.model indexed.

Any idea how I can speed this up? Thanks!

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | company1  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2853 |                                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | company2  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 8986 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+-------+---+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you post the result of EXPLAIN? Probably doing an unindexed search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query is not conceptually identical to yours, but maybe you want something like this? I am quite sure it will give you the same result as yours:

```
select
  *
from
  company1 inner join company2
  on company1.manufacturer = company2.manufacturer
where
  company2.model LIKE CONCAT(company1.model,'%')
```

**EDIT:** i also removed your `left join` and put an `inner join`. If the join doesn't succeed, `company2.model` is always `null` and `NULL LIKE 'Something%'` can never be true.

Comment: this should be a lot faster, given the `manufacturer` of both tables is indexed, too.

Answer (score 1):

One way to speed this up is to remove the `LIKE CONCAT()` from the join condition.

MySQL is not able to use an index for substring based searches like that, so your query results in a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Your `EXPLAIN` shows that you have no indexes that can be used.

Appropriate indexes on both tables would help. Either a single index on `(manufacturer)` or a composite `(manufacturer, model)`:

```
ALTER TABLE company1
  ADD INDEX manufacturer_model_IDX       --- this is just a name (of your choice)
    (manufacturer, model) ;              --- for the index

ALTER TABLE company2
  ADD INDEX manufacturer_model_IDX
    (manufacturer, model) ;
```